# Primeng Checkbox.css is not loading correctly

Tags: angular, primeng, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I am using Primeng with Single SPA angular application. I am using
import { CheckboxModule } from 'primeng/checkbox';
and imported into import section as well.
Also I have used ButtonModule and Inputtextmodule from primeng, I am able to use ButtonModule and Inputtextmodule components properly in my application. But while using checkbox it gives error in console "application 'login' died in status SKIP_BECAUSE_BROKEN: "Failed to load checkbox.css"

I tried to analyze the issue and found that in main.js file it was using
styleUrls: ['./checkbox.css'],
only in case of checkbox. For Button and InputText it was not using styleUrls.
In angular.json I have used the below styles:

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "src/assets/layout/css/layout-light.css",
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
        ],
```

styles.scss contains the below code:

```
@import "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
// @import "../node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.scss";
@import "../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import "../node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism-coy.css";
@import "../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.css";
@import "../node_modules/@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.css";
@import "../node_modules/@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.css";
@import "assets/demo/flags/flags.css";
```

And app.module.ts file contains the import statements as below:

```
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext';
import { CheckboxModule } from 'primeng/checkbox';
```

Dependencies from package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^12.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^12.2.3",
"@angular/common": "~12.0.4",
"@angular/compiler": "~12.0.4",
"@angular/core": "~12.0.4",
"@angular/forms": "~12.0.4",
"@angular/material": "^12.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.4",
"@angular/router": "~12.0.4",
"@fullcalendar/core": "^5.9.0",
"auth0-js": "^9.16.2",
"chart.js": "^3.5.1",
"cpx": "^1.5.0",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^12.0.3",
"ngx-toastr": "^14.1.0",
"primeicons": "^4.1.0",
"primeng": "^12.1.1",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"single-spa": "^5.9.3",
"single-spa-angular": "^5.0.2",
"tslib": "^2.1.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
```

},

Thanks

Comment: Please, do provide your `angular.json` ; the module where you want to import your checkbox

Comment: Hi @Exomus I have added code from angular.json. your thoughts on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also provide your angular version and your primeng version you are currently using ?

Comment: I have added dependencies from package.json